# Suppose $f:A\bigoplus M \to A\bigoplus N$ and $g: A \to A$, where $g = \pi_A\circ f\circ l_A$, are isomorphisms of $R-module$. Prove that $M\cong N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose $f:A\bigoplus M \to A\bigoplus N$ and $g: A \to A$, where $g = \pi_A\circ f\circ l_A$, are isomorphisms of $R$-module. Prove that $M\cong N$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*. The  map $f: A\oplus M\to A\oplus N$ is given by a matrix
$$ X = \left[ \begin{matrix} \lambda  & f_2  \\ g_1 & g_2\end{matrix}\right]$$
where $\lambda$ is an isomorphism. Multiplying by the matrix
$$ \left[ \begin{matrix} \lambda^{-1} & 0  \\ 0 & 1_N \end{matrix}\right]$$
you can assume that $g$ is the *identity* of $A$. Since $f$ is an isomorphism, there exist some matrix
$$ Y=\left[ \begin{matrix} h_1  & h_2  \\ j_1 & j_2\end{matrix}\right]$$
that is an inverse to $X$. What do the equations $XY=1$ and $YX=1$ give?

Comment: Here $g$ is an $R$-isomorphism of $A$

Comment: @AlexL Ah, my bad, I'm too used to use $A$ for rings. The procedure still works, though!

Answer (score 0):

Write $f(a,m)= (g(a),h(a)) + (\phi(m),\psi(m))=(g(a)+\phi(m),h(a)+\psi(m))$, accordingly to the decompositions of the direct sums $A \oplus M$ and $A \oplus N$.

Since $f$ is onto, for all $n \in N$, there exists $(a,m) \in A \oplus M$ such that $f(a,m)=(0,n)$. This gives $n=-h g^{-1} \phi(m)+ \psi(m)$. This suggest to define $\alpha(m):=-h g^{-1} \phi(m)+ \psi(m)$. We have seen that $\alpha$ is onto.

Now, assume $\alpha(m)=0$. One has $f(-g^{-1}\phi(m),m)=(0,0)$. Since $f$ is one-to-one, this implies $m=0$.

Finally $\alpha$ is an isomorphism $M \to N$